# Whitelisting an unsigned kext in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, driver, code-signing, macos-catalina, kernel-extension

I've recently bought an old Alesis io26 Firewire Audio interface. The last driver release was only working on mountain Lion and older. After some time I've managed to install said drivers on Catalina, by manually dragging the midi driver into /Library/Audio/MIDI drivers and installing the kernel extension into /System/Library/Extensions via KEXT droplet. The problem I have now is that my mbpro only recognises the Interface if my SIP is disabled. I've heard that the driver is not signed and that this is the reason why the SIP is preventing it from working. So as a total noob, how can I somehow whitelist that kext so that I don't have to go to recovery mode and disable SIP every time I want to record some Audio.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 "correct" ways of doing this are probably unlikely:

- Get the original developer to sign the kext
- Somehow persuade Apple to add it to macOS's built-in whitelist
- If you have a kext signing certificate yourself, you can sign it. (Apparently, Apple no longer issues these, however.)

The best you can do in practice is probably to only disable the kext signing part of SIP by using the command

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

instead of

```
csrutil disable
```

Of course, this leaves your system open to being attacked via unsigned kexts, though I've not heard of any malware that specifically targets Macs with kext signing disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question is for Catalina. We cannot partially disable SIP by running with --without kext. from Mojave this option is disabled and one has to either enable or disable it from Recovery OS.